# Undefined array key[ Will it be a problem?

Tags: php

I want to ask a if undefined array key can cause problems later on.

I have a product list in php file where when i choose different options like colour and size, it shows different prices and images accordingly. Everything works fine but in the apache error log it mentions an array key is undefined.

Will this cause problems?

Comment: A detailed and correct answer can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4261133/notice-undefined-variable-notice-undefined-index-warning-undefined-arr)

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Of course, an error is always bad. You should try to figure out, what the error is and which key is causing the error.
It can crash your application, create undefined behavior or other side effects.

If the key is essential, it must be present. Otherwise, you could test the array, before accessing the array:

```
$arr = ['foo' => 42];
if (isset($arr['bar']) {
    echo $arr['bar'];
} else {
    // do some error handling
}
```

Comment: Thanks Chris. The undefined arrays are checkboxes that are not checked. Should I be concerned or should I add conditions to prevent the errors coming?

Comment: You should always prevent errors. You can add conditions to prevent it, but this blocks only the symptom and doesn't solve the issue. I would suggest setting the state of the checkboxes in the array, so the value is set and can be accessed.

Comment: I'll do that! thank you for your time

Comment: "*an error is always bad*" - This is not considered an error, but a notice... Your last comment doesn't make any sense at all. There is no reason to predefine "checkboxes" in PHP. A simple `isset($_POST['chk_name'])` or `isset($_GET['chk_name'])` will suffice

Comment: @DarkBee Yes you are right, it's a notice and not an error. Anyway, you should not access an undefined array key.
And yes, you are also right, that a simple check would be better.